# Disable scroll except for 1 section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am creating a website at the moment where scrolling will be disabled on the entire website (it's made out of sections, all are as tall as screen height except for 1 section, because that one is too large..).

I've been looking around to see if any plug-ins exist for this yet, but haven't had any luck, yet.

Would anyone know a plug-in or how to do this?

It would help me a great deal.

Comment: You don't need plugins to do this. It will work if the containers are properly sized. Post your code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to post the code right now. I can, however, give you the website I'm working on atm. www.digitalcreation.nl/oamkb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all of your site has the style `overflow:hidden` then you can target the one section by id or class and make it `overflow-y:scroll`

ps the link you posted is a 404 error

Comment: fixed the link. your solution doesn't seem to work, though :(

Comment: so it looks like you are referring to section 2. The height is `min-height:100vh` so content is being allowed to expand the section beyond 100vh. if you change this rule to `height: 100vh` it will hide the excess content. if you then add the rule `overflow-y:scroll` to just that section you will be able to scroll through the content in the section

Comment: I've got it working now... but it's glitching out a lot, like: it won't recognize the scroll. Would you know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to disable or enable scroll for a containing element by setting the overflow property to none.
However, in your case, I guess there is no reason for a script, you can simply set the overflow property in the style of the offending element.

Here's the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/tqkr9vyz/2/

```
        function setScroll(elementName, s) {
          document.getElementsByName(elementName).style.overflow = s;
        }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to work for me, even on the jsfiddle you linked.